# How to refresh a Discord user token with python

Tags: python, discord, python-requests-html

So I've been trying to make a program using Python that refreshes my Discord user token once every five minutes, but most of the tutorials online are about refreshing your Oauth2 access token, so I am currently very confused. Can anyone help me on the modules and functions to use, or are the Oauth2 access token and user token same things. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your Discord Token change when changing the password of your account so you will need to change your password every 5 minutes using some api calls and get the current token from another specific api call. you can find the api call urls and the data you need to post / get in the browser devconsole.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to

- send your username password to the discord API endpoint https://discord.com/api/v9/auth/login
- then potentially do a follow up API request for 2FA https://discord.com/api/v9/auth/mfa/totp

The moment your password changed, you will need to re fetch too as tokens challenge against your password hash stored in discords DB's. Refreshing every 5 minutes is also a little excessive, every 1-6 hours will do

Below is a short script I created. Its a token fetcher class that you can throw in a file and import. Or you can rip some code and simplify it if you want. Running the file itself has a main function simply just to test it

Note that in order for this to work, I had to include some weird headers that discord requires

```py
import asyncio
import json

import aiohttp
import maskpass
import pyotp

DISCORD_BASE_URL = "https://discord.com/api/v9"


class DiscordLogin:
    @classmethod
    async def login(cls, username, password, totp=None):
        self = cls()
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        totp = str(totp)
        if len(totp) != 6:
            self.totp = totp
        else:
            self.totp = None
        self.token = None

        url = f"{DISCORD_BASE_URL}/auth/login"
        headers = {
            "accept": "*/*",
            "accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
            "content-type": "application/json",
            "sec-ch-ua": '"Chromium";v="108", "Not?A_Brand";v="8"',
            "sec-ch-ua-mobile": "?0",
            "sec-ch-ua-platform": '"Windows"',
            "sec-fetch-dest": "empty",
            "sec-fetch-mode": "cors",
            "sec-fetch-site": "same-origin",
            "x-debug-options": "bugReporterEnabled",
            "x-discord-locale": "en-US",
        }
        body = {
            "login": self.username,
            "password": self.password,
        }
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession(headers=headers) as session:
            r = await session.post(url, data=json.dumps(body))
            r = await r.json()
        self.token = r.get("token")
        self.ticket = r.get("ticket")
        if self.token is None:
            assert self.ticket is not None, "Invalid Login"
            if totp is not None:
                await self.mfa(totp)
        return self

    async def mfa(self, code=None):
        assert self.ticket is not None, "No MFA Ticket"
        if self.totp is not None:
            totp = pyotp.TOTP(self.totp)
            code = totp.now()
        elif code is not None:
            code = code
        else:
            assert "TOTP Required"

        url = f"{DISCORD_BASE_URL}/auth/mfa/totp"
        headers = {
            "accept": "*/*",
            "accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
            "content-type": "application/json",
            "sec-ch-ua": '"Chromium";v="108", "Not?A_Brand";v="8"',
            "sec-ch-ua-mobile": "?0",
            "sec-ch-ua-platform": '"Windows"',
            "sec-fetch-dest": "empty",
            "sec-fetch-mode": "cors",
            "sec-fetch-site": "same-origin",
            "x-debug-options": "bugReporterEnabled",
            "x-discord-locale": "en-US",
        }
        body = {
            "code": code,
            "ticket": self.ticket,
            "login_source": None,
            "gift_code_sku_id": None,
        }

        async with aiohttp.ClientSession(headers=headers) as session:
            r = await session.post(url, data=json.dumps(body))
            r = await r.json()
        token = r.get("token")
        retry = r.get("retry_after")
        if token is not None:
            self.token = token
        elif retry is not None:
            raise Exception(f"Retry after {retry}s")
        else:
            raise Exception("Invalid Login")
        return self


async def main():
    user = input("User: ")
    pswd = maskpass.askpass("Password: ")
    totp = input("TOTP: ")
    x = await DiscordLogin.login(user, pswd, totp)
    print(x.token[:5])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
```